# How to update password using angularjs and rails/devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm having a problem trying to update a users password using a simple form with old and new password. The problem is I post `{"user[current_password]":$scope.user.password,"user[password]":$scope.user.newpassword}` data to my `Devise::RegistrationsController` and I get a simple `422 Unprocessable Entity` response. Where am I going wrong?

This is my html

```
<div ng-controller="PasswordCtrl">
    <form id="password-card" class="row" style="display:none;" name="password_form" ng-submit="changePassword()" novalidate>
        <div class="span5">
            <div class="form-inputs">
                <label for="nPass"><%= I18n.t("registration.edit.current_password") %></label>
                <input name="uPass" class="required" type="password" ng-model="user.password" required >
                <div ng-show="password_form.uPass.$dirty && password_form.uPass.$invalid">Missing:
                  <span ng-show="password_form.uPass.$error.required">You must provided your current password.</span>
                </div>                    

                <label for="nPass"><%= I18n.t("registration.edit.new_password") %></label>
                <input name="nPass" class="required" type="password" ng-model="user.newpassword" required >
                <div ng-show="password_form.nPass.$dirty && password_form.nPass.$invalid">Missing:
                  <span ng-show="password_form.nPass.$error.required">Tell us your new password.</span>
                </div>                    
                <button id="x" type="submit" ng-disabled="!password_form.$valid" class="button secondary prefix">Breyta</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my angular controller

```
var PasswordCtrl=function($scope,registrationService, $http){

    $scope.changePassword=function(){
        console.log("current_password",password_form.uPass.value);
        $http({
            method: 'PUT', 
            url: '/skraning.json', 
            headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            data: {"user[current_password]":$scope.user.password,"user[password]":$scope.user.newpassword}
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("done",data);
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your data object passed is not valid( user[current_password] & user[password]) : try like this with quotes

`data: {"user['current_password']":$scope.user.password,"user['password']":$scope.user.newpassword}`